# Django email template encoding

Tags: django, python-3.x, django-forms, django-templates, django-views

I maked a view with a form, that should send message on user email, but i have a problev with encoding. My template have some kirillic letters, and if i try to send mail i get an error:

```
'ascii' codec can't encode characters in position 325-329: ordinal not in range(128)
```

If i change text in my template to english letters everything works.

View:

```
def index(request):
    seos = SEO.objects.get(id__exact=1)
    socs = Social_networks.objects.get(id__exact=1)
    globs = globalapp.objects.get(id__exact=1)
    index = Index.objects.get(id__exact=1)

    form = ContactForm(request.POST)
    formmm = ContactusForm(request.POST)
    email = globalapp.objects.values_list('emailfb', flat=True).get(id=1)


    if form.is_valid():
        subject = form.cleaned_data['subject']
        sender = form.cleaned_data['sender']
        message = form.cleaned_data['message']
        fille = form.cleaned_data['fille']
        recepients = email

        from_email, to =  sender, recepients


        html_content = loader.render_to_string('globalapp/chunks/email_tpl.html',
        {'subject': subject, 'sender':sender, 'message':message, 'fille':fille})

        msg = EmailMultiAlternatives(subject, html_content, from_email, [to])

        msg.send()

        if request.method == 'POST':
            subject = request.POST['subject']
            email = request.POST['sender']
            message = request.POST['message']
            form = 'Шапка'

            post.objects.create(
                subject = subject,
                email = email,
                message = message,
                form = form
            )
            return HttpResponse('')
    return render(request, 'globalapp/index.html', {'seos': seos, 
                                                  'socs': socs,
                                                  'globs': globs,
                                                  'index': index,
                                                  'form': form,
                                                  'formmm': formmm })
```

Template:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
</head>
    <h2>Новое сообщение с сайта!</h2>

    <p>Имя:  {{ subject }}</p>
    <p>Email:  {{ sender }}</p>
    <p>Сообщение:  {{ message }}</p>
</html>
```

Ill tryed already to use `.endoce('utf-8')` with template, but didnt get any results yet.

Comment: Please indicate on which line the error occurs.

Comment: On line `msg.send()`

Comment: if you open a django shell, `from django.conf import settings` and print `settings.DEFAULT_CHARSET` what do you get?

Comment: >>> from django.conf import settings
>>> settings.DEFAULT_CHARSET
'utf-8'

Comment: can you add the full stack trace to your question? This is strange.

Comment: http://joxi.ru/V2VZWvGCxlEGG2 here is a screenshot of what django giving to me.

Comment: which version of python?

Comment: no idea. this doesn't make sense. try adding `msg.encoding = 'utf-8'` before `msg.send()` but it shouldn't make a difference.

Comment: i already tryed this, no difference. I have old versions: python 3.4 and django 2.0, but customer wants it to be on russian hosting, where for some reason i cant install python version > then 3.4. On pythonanywhere code works perfectly

Comment: You're using the console email backend, maybe your console doesn't allow non-ascii output? Try using a proper email backend as you would in production (e.g. SMTP) and see if that works. If it does, then maybe change your code to differentiate between backends.

Comment: LOL WORKED. Thank you very much!